# Split a file in linux based on character present

Tags: linux, bash, split

i tried to find a solution to this problem on the forums, but wasn't able to either understand some of the solutions.

I'm working with DNA data, and i have 2 files.
The first file (a) is a file containing all sequence headers. (name etc)
Each header has its own line.
Example:

```
>title1
>title2
>title3
>some other title
```

The second file (b) contains the contents of those headers.
Each line corresponds to the 1st file.

```
GAGTTGGAAAGAG
GCTGCCCTGAGATCGTNNNN
GTGCAGTGATNNAGTG
ACTG
```

I'm making a program which searches for unknown letters in the sequences.
Normally you would assume that file 2 only has characters A C T & G in it.

I want to make 2 files:

- A file with both header + sequence (1st tab = header, second tab = sequence) with entries with only A C T and G in them
- A file with both header + sequence (1st tab = header, second tab = sequence) only this time we have only entries which contain other letters. (for example N)

I tried this so far:

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line" | tr -d "A" | tr -d "C" | tr -d "T" | tr -d "G" | tr -d "\n" | wc -c
done <sequenceOnly.txt >unkownLines.txt
```

This calculates how often an unknown character occurs in the (b) file.
If this value is larger then 0, I want to use this line to place header + sequence in the unknownLines.txt file, but I'm stuck :/

Expected output file 1 (has only ACTG):

```
>title1             GAGTTGGAAAGAG
>some other title   ACTG
```

Expected output file 2 (has other stuff):

```
>title2            GCTGCCCTGAGATCGTNNNN
>title3            GTGCAGTGATNNAGTG
```

Comment: You need to post both input files *(a sample of lines at least)* and the post the expected outputs.

Comment: you could use `tr -d "ACTG"` instead of `tr -d "A" | tr -d "T" ...`

Comment: You don't need to pipe `tr` commands like that; just delete the set of chars you want.

Comment: You don't need the `read/while` either.  Just do `tr -d ACTG < sequenceOnly.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put the data together with paste, then separate with awk:

```
paste header sequence | 
    awk '$NF ~ /^[ACTG]*$/ {print > "file1"; next }1'  > file2
```

The pasting puts the data into two columns, and the `awk` checks if the last column contains only the letters `ACTG`.  If it does, the line is written to the file `file1`.  (Empty sequences will also be printed.)  If not, the line is written to `file2`.

Comment: Fails when the header contains spaces change `$2` to `$NF` to fix.